# Get Id of <a> selector using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="Tab1" href="">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a id="Tab2" href="">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a id="Tab3" href="">Tab3</a></li>
        <li><a id="Tab4" href="">Tab4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var IdName = $("a").attr('id');
        alert(IdName);
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click the hyperlink, it always shows id of the first hyperlink. Why ? How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an event handler, `this` is the element you want.

Change

```
var IdName = $("a").attr('id');
```

to

```
var IdName = this.id;
```

Note: it makes no sense to use `$(this).attr('id')`, this is slow and verbose for no reason, always use the direct `this.id`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this)` inside the `click` event handler. `$(this)` inside event handler is the `anchor` that is clicked.

```
$("a").on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    // return false OR e.preventDefault to stop redirection
});
```

Comment: Why DownVote? Please add Comments here

Comment: Both alert($(this).attr('id'))  and alert(this.id) working fine. Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `attr()` on `$('a')` which will give you attribute of first matched element. Use `$(this)` to get current clicked anchor tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("a").click(function(){
          var IdName = $(this).attr('id');
          alert(IdName);
      }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. U only told why it's giving first matched element. Now I am clear.